# Why rollapply is much slower with fill=NA and function return multiple values?

Tags: r, rollapply

If a function return 2 or more values, and using `fill = NA`, `rollapply` become much slower. 
Is there any ways to avoid it?

```
f1= function(v)c(mean(v)+ median(v))    #return vector of length 1
f2= function(v)c(mean(v), median(v))    #return vector of length 2


v = rnorm(1000)
microbenchmark(rollapplyr(v, 20, f1), rollapplyr(v,20, f1, fill=NA) )

#                             expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#            rollapplyr(v, 20, f1) 50.84485 53.68726 57.21892 54.63793 57.78519 75.88305   100
# rollapplyr(v, 20, f1, fill = NA) 52.11355 54.69866 59.73473 56.20600 63.10546 99.96493   100

microbenchmark(rollapplyr(v, 20, f2), rollapplyr(v,20, f2, fill=NA) )

#                             expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#            rollapplyr(v, 20, f2) 51.77687 52.29403 56.80307 53.44605 56.65524 105.6713   100
# rollapplyr(v, 20, f2, fill = NA) 69.93853 71.08953 76.48056 72.21896 80.58282 151.4455   100
```

Comment: 1-You haven't specified the packages you are using. 2- You haven't even showed the measurement units. It seems like a small penalty for doing an additional operation. 3- If you want to improve speed check out https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppRoll/RcppRoll.pdf

Comment: The extra time seems to be linear with length of `v` above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is to be found in the speed of using `fill.na` on different types of data, as happens internally in the `rollapply()`function. Your `f1` returns a single vector, whereas `f2` returns a matrix of two columns (well, both are `zoo` objects actually, but you catch my drift).

The speed decrease for inserting the NA is not proportionate to the mere doubling of the number of elements, as this shows:

```
library(zoo)
library(microbenchmark)

v <- zoo(rnorm(1000))
m <- zoo(matrix(rnorm(2000), ncol=2))
ix <- seq(1000)>50
microbenchmark(na.fill(v, NA, ix), na.fill(m, NA, ix))

# Unit: microseconds
#               expr      min        lq       mean    median         uq      max neval
# na.fill(v, NA, ix)  402.861   511.912   679.1114   659.597   754.8385  4716.46   100
# na.fill(m, NA, ix) 9746.643 10091.038 14281.5598 14057.304 17589.9670 22249.96   100
```